# Approximating integral $p$-adic matrices of order 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, p-adic-number-theory, matrix-norms, unitary-matrices

Let $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. We consider the maximum norm $\| \cdot \|$ on $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, which coincides with the operator norm with respect to the maximum norm on $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$. If $\|A^2 - I\|$ is small enough, can I find some $B \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ such that $B^2 = I$ and $\|A - B\|$ is small? That is, if $A$ is almost of order 2, is $A$ close to an element of order $2$?

This is true for $U(n)$ with the norm induced from $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ (notice that $U(n)$ is maximal compact in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ just as $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is maximal compact in $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$). It can be proven by first diagonalizing $A$ over $U(n)$ and then choosing $B$ diagonal with entries $\pm 1$ according to the sign of the real parts of the corresponding entries of $A$. So diagonalization is used, and the order on the reals, both of which do not pass over to the $p$-adics.

Comment: If the typographical difference between $||A||$ and $\|A\|$ is not conspicuous enough for you, consider the difference between $\|A\|\|B\|$ (coded as \|A\|\|B\|) and $||A|| ||B||$ (coded as ||A|| ||B||). That is why I edited as I did.

Comment: Since $A^2 - I = (A - I)(A + I)$, if $A^2 - I$ is small then either $(A+I)$ or $(A - I)$ is sort of small. So either $B = I$ or $B = -I$ ought to work, right?

Comment: ah i see, the max norm isn't submultiplicative. sorry!

Comment: (also the question wants $B^2 = I$ in it, right?)

Comment: @hunter Thanks, I added $B^2 = I$. The norm is indeed submultiplicative, but you only get $\| A^2 - I \| \leq \| A - I \| \| A + I \|$, so the two terms on the right hand side are not necessarily small.

Comment: Well, what you call the "order" of the reals can be replaced by deciding for a diagonal entry $\lambda$ whether $\lvert \lambda -1 \rvert$ or $\lvert \lambda-(-1) \rvert$ is smaller, and that can be done for $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ being the archimedean or the $p$-adic value. Further, the statement is true for matrices in Jordan normal form and of course you can conjugate matrices to that over $p$-adics (maybe extending scalars a bit) as well; and finally, whatever shows that diagonalisation does not destroy the statement should show that conjugating to Jordan form does not destroy it.

Comment: In short, I would think that you can prove this in greater generality with the same method, but if you see an obstacle here which I overlook, please point it out and I'd happily give it more thought.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I agree about the order, that won't be a problem. In the unitary case, the diagonalization can be done with unitary matrices, and the norm is invariant under multiplication by those. In my case, the norm is invariant by integral matrices but you will most likely not be able to put in Jordan normal form using those, right? The hope is that there might be a bound on the norm of the diagonalizing matrix in terms of $A$...

Comment: @frafour: Agreed, that seems to be the crucial part.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg in fact, up to normalizing the columns of the diagonalizing matrix $P$ we may assume that $||P|| = 1$. Then it can be shown that $||P^{-1}|| = |det(P)|^{-1}$, which can potentially be large. Another problem is that the matrix $B$ obtained with this procedure may also lie in $GL_n(K)$, where $K$ is (the ball of radius 1 of) some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, not necessarily in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, at least for odd $p$. It follows from the following theorem of Brawley from "Similar Involutory Matrices (mod $p^m$)":

**Theorem:** Let $p$ be an odd prime, $m \geq 1$, and let $A$ be an integral matrix such that $A^2 = I \mod p^m$. Then there exist integral matrices $P, Q$ and $1 \leq t \leq n$ such that $P$ and $Q$ are inverse $\mod p^m$ and $PAQ = J_t \mod p^m$, where $J_t = diag(I_t, -I_{n-t})$.

Now $A^2 = I \mod p^m$ is equivalent to $\|A^2 - I\| \leq p^m$. The fact that $P$ is invertible $\mod p^m$ implies that a representative is in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and so $\|PAP^{-1} - J_t\| \leq p^m$ too. Choosing $B = P^{-1}J_tP$ and using that the norm is invariant under $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, we conclude.

A similar theorem is available for $p = 2$, see the last section of "Involutory matrices over finite commutative rings" by Brawley and Gamble, although the canonical form is more complicated than just $J_t$. I did not spend much time on it (I am happy with $p$ odd for the time being) but I believe it should still work.